# event.target not working for me in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m doing a angular stuff for my work.  I have set of element with ng-show and i m passing "custom" on each element ng-show. But its not working for me. i m new to angular. Can anyone help me to fix this issue

My need is  Every element has UL with hided state. when i click one element its show corresponding ul and all other element's ul has hided. If i click another one element, previous opened one ul should closed and clicked element's ul should opened.

My Code is below

```
app.controller('multiSelect',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.custom = false;
        $scope.toggleCustom = function(event) {
            $scope.custom = false;
            $(event.target).custom = true;
            console.log($scope.custom);
            console.log($(event.target).custom);

        };
}]);
```

My Html is

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td  ng-controller="multiSelect" ng-click="toggleCustom($event)" ng-class="{active : isSelected(site)}">
                             <div class="upvalue">1</div><div class="downvalue">{{selected}}</div>
                             <ul class="reveal" ng-show="custom">
                              <li class="pointer"></li>
                              <li ng-repeat="site in sites" ><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setMaster(site)">{{site.name}}</a></li>
                             </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td  ng-controller="multiSelect" ng-click="toggleCustom($event)" ng-class="{active : isSelected(site)}">
                             <div class="upvalue">2</div><div class="downvalue">{{selected}}</div>
                             <ul class="reveal" ng-show="custom">
                              <li class="pointer"></li>
                              <li ng-repeat="site in sites" ><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setMaster(site)">{{site.name}}</a></li>
                             </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td  ng-controller="multiSelect" ng-click="toggleCustom($event)" ng-class="{active : isSelected(site)}">
                             <div class="upvalue">3</div><div class="downvalue">{{selected}}</div>
                             <ul class="reveal" ng-show="custom">
                              <li class="pointer"></li>
                              <li ng-repeat="site in sites" ><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="setMaster(site)">{{site.name}}</a></li>
                             </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Add HTML too, jsfiddle/plunker will also help

Comment: Added my htmls. Pls check

Comment: you appear to be mixing angular and JQuery in the same controller here.  This kind of logic is recommended to be put in a directive.  I believe that you could solve this issue by removing the JQuery invoke, and just doing `event.target.custom = true;`, but I don't really recommend this approach.

Comment: in IE? which is event.srcElement btw.

Comment: event.target.custom = true also not working in my case :(

Comment: Could you help me to create a directive for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add $event when calling this function. For Example

```
<a href="#" ng-click="toggleCustom($event)" > Toggle </a>
```

Comment: Added my htmls. pls check

Answer (score 0):

Set controller and event in html code

```
<div ng-controller = "multiSelect">
  <button ng-click = "toggleCustom(evt)" >Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Added my htmls. pls check